# How to display inscription depending on the result from the database?

Tags: php, mysql

In the database, the status column can have two values; friend and waiting. I want to display the inscription **friend** if the person is my friend, the inscription **waiting** if I am waiting for an answer, and the inscription **add** if I do not have it in my friends. I created a function for this, but it shows nothing.

```
 public function status()
 {
    $id =  $_GET['id'];
    $session  = $_SESSION['id'];
    $sql = $this->database->connect()->prepare("SELECT status FROM user JOIN friend ON user.id = friend.request_from_id where  request_to_id = :id and request_from_id = :session OR  request_to_id = :session and request_from_id = :id");
    $sql->bindParam(':session',$id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->bindParam(':id',$session, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->execute();

    if($sql->rowCount())
    {
        $row = $sql->fetch();

        if($row['status']== 'friend']
        {
            return 'friend';
        }
        else if($row['status']=='waiting')
        {
            return 'Waiting';
        }
    }
    else if(!($id != $session))
    {
        return  'This is me';
    }
    else
        return 'Add to friend';
}
```

Comment: Where do you think `$row` is coming from? You forgot to fetch it. Double check against a worked example

Comment: I add  $row = $sql->fetch(); under if($sql)->rowCount()) but it changes nothing.

Comment: In the case where status is neither "friend" nor "waiting" (is NULL possible?), this function will not return a value.

Comment: Function then should return 'Add to friend'.

Comment: Perhaps it should, but it won't :) If there are rows, but the value of status is neither of those, no default return value is specified.

Comment: `$pole` and `$pole2` also seem to be undefined. And what debugging have you done? Narrow down the issue.

Comment: let's start with the function returns nothing if the user is friend.

Comment: It is a minor thing, but in your SQL you are mixing `AND` and `OR` which assumes operator precedence. This is totally fine as long as you've got that memorized (I know I don't), but I'd recommend using parenthesis to avoid any ambiguity for anyone else that needs to read that code.

Comment: I know, but the function return nothing and I don't know why

Comment: If that's the most you can tell us then that's because you haven't debugged it. Do you understand how to do basic debugging of your code?

Comment: No, I don;t understand it

Comment: Debugging is a vital skill for a programmer. It's just as important as being able to write the code. You should be learning it at the same time. How do you expect to ever fix any problems in your code if you can't do basic tests on it? Here's a beginner's guide: http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/basic-debugging/ . Your objective should be to work out what path the code is taking, and what the values of significant variables are which would affect that.

Comment: var_dump($row) returns friend. but display add to friend

Comment: What **exactly** does it return?

Comment: P.S. As an aside `!($id != $session)` is a bit of a weird way to write the logic. `($id == $session)` would be much clearer.

Comment: @ChrisHaas FWIW, I don't think it's a minor thing. Seems prettty major to me!

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)